# any way to create awaitable EF query?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

Is there any way to create an async function that returns an EF query result?
Any way I try to code it VS doesn't like it and says they aren't awaitable.

```
 Private Async Function GetZiptaxByZipcode(ByVal zipcode As String) As Task(Of List(Of ziptax))
        Using db
            Dim list As List(Of ziptax) = Await (From d In db.ziptaxes
                    Where d.PostalCode = zipcode
                    Select d).ToList()

        End Using
    End Function
```

Error: System.Collections.Generic.List(of T) is not awaitable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `async`/`wait` this way. `await` must be applied on a `Task`, and your `ToList()` method doesn't return a task.

So you would need to use [`ToListAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

Do note this requires Entity Framework 6. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx